# Motorsport Lap Chart using ListLinePlot

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

I'm trying to take a table of motorsport lap positions and plot a lap chart similar to this http://www.fia.com/en-GB/sport/championships/f1/2010/bahrain/Pages/lap_chart.aspx.

Each row corresponds to a lap, with the first lap in the first row.  The car numbers are listed across each row in the order they pass the start/finish line
The table may look like this (4-car race, 6 laps:

1 3 2 4
1 3 2 4
1 3 4 2
3 1 4 2
3 1 4 2
3 4 1 2

In the above example, the order was 1,3,2,4 after the first lap, and by the end of the 6-lap race, car 3 won, car 4 was in second, and so on.

It's easy to plot this incorrectly, I did this:

```
ListLinePlot[Table[Position[data,x],{x,4}]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This does produce a lap chart, but it has 1st position at the bottom and 4th position at the top, and what I really need is the y-axis to run 4-3-2-1 so 1st position is at the top.

How can I reverse the y-axis so it runs from 1(top) to n(bottom)?

Comment: BarChart and Histogram as of v8 have a new option, ScalingFunctions, which can take the value "Reverse". It's a pity it doesn't work for normal Plots.

Comment: Ron, when a car drops out of the race, how is that represented? By the way, welcome to StackOverflow.

Comment: Ron, Welcome to Stack Overflow. Nice question, including the part about drivers not finishing.

Comment: Ron, please be sure to vote on and accept answers.  See:  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5235/ and the main FAQ which that is from: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/

Answer (score 8):

Just use Quadrant 4 to settle the position-on-screen problem.

This also works for DNF!  (Drivers that did not finish).

First place is plotted at y = -1, second place is plotted at y = -2, etc.
Note how `y` is replaced by `-y` in `{{lap_, y_} :>  {lap - 1, -y}}` below.

`lap` was decremented by 1 because I included data for the starting position (lap=zero).

---

A minor rewrite, to work with different numbers of drivers and laps, and reformat the code for increased legibility. - *Mr.Wizard*

---

```
data = 
  {{1, 3, 2, 4},
   {1, 3, 2, 4},
   {1, 3, 4, 2},
   {3, 1, 4, 2},
   {3, 1, 4, 2},
   {3, 4, 1, 2}};

{p, n} = {Max@data, Length@data};

ticks = {#, #} &@Array[{-#, #} &, p];
ticks[[All, 1, 2]] = {"Pole", "Winner"};

PrependTo[data, Range@p];  (* add starting position *)

ListLinePlot[
 Replace[
   Array[data~Position~# &, p],
   {lap_, y_} :> {lap - 1, -y},
   {2}
 ],
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel ->
  {"Laps Completed",
   "Starting Positions",
   "Laps Completed",
   "Final Positions"},
 GridLines -> {Range[0, n + 1], None},
 FrameTicks -> {ticks, {All, All}},
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-.7, -.3 - p}},
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[.01]
]
```

[image: race cars]

Here's the case where car #1 (the one that started in the Pole Position) dropped out before completing the final two laps. Notice that car #3 automatically advanced by one position.

[image: DNF]

Comment: Very pretty.  Please explain the position logic.

Comment: Thanks everyone, these are some really good ideas.  I played with some solutions and the ones I tried work fine... as long as all the cars that started the race finish the race.  Now I'm playing with how to resolve the issue where you have DNFs, because that messes up the simple "reversal" that I've seen.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The Pole position (#1) finished in third place. The second starting position finished in fourth place. The car in the third starting position won the race. The car starting in fourth position finished second.

Comment: David, now I see it.  I think.  Does car #2 spend three laps in third place?

Comment: Car 1 spends 3 laps in 1st place, then drops to 2nd for 2 laps, then finishes in 3rd.  Car 2 spends the first 2 laps in 3rd, then drops to last place for the remainder of the race.  Car 3 spends 3 laps in 2nd, then takes 1st and finishes there.  Car 4 is in 4th for 2 laps, then moves to 3rd for 3 laps, and finally finishes in 2nd.  I should have had a DNF in there to make it realistic.

Comment: @Ron Thanks, I had an error in my replacement rules. I was able to solve it by using the quadrant 4. At least I think it now works ok. Notice that I started with lap 0 (ie. the starting position).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard  There was an error in an earlier version. I removed the replacement rules and used a more straightforward way to represent positions on screen,using Quadrant 4.

Comment: David, your answer is much nicer than mine.  If I may have permission to make a few tweaks to yours, I will delete mine.

Comment: @Mr. Wizard  Go right ahead. And thanks for the nudge earlier. When I troubleshot my code, I stumbled on a much simpler solution.

Comment: Wow, that's fantastic.  Thanks again, I learned a ton on this fun problem.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Nice tweaks! Thanks for tidying things up.

Comment: You're welcome.  Your graphic is certainly the nicest, I am glad I could help streamline the code.  Most importantly I removed "magic numbers" so that it will work with other data sets (more/less cars/laps).

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Ah, now I know what you meant by the "magic numbers"!

Comment: David, I made another change, because I realized the replacement rule broke the plot when there were only two drivers.  By limiting the replacement to "level 2" it is made safe.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Your idea of using `Array` to build the ticks before adding "Pole" and "Winner", is cleaner, and makes nice use of the number of drivers and laps that were inferred from the data.

Answer (score 7):

Reverse the order of the positions, and then relabel the ticks:

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[Position[data, x] /. {xx_, yy_} :> {xx, 5 - yy}, {x, 4}],
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {{1, 4}, {2, 3}, {3, 2}, {4, 1}}}, 
 PlotStyle -> Thickness[.01]]
```

[image]

Comment: Michael, congratulation on 4,000 rep!

Answer (score 4):

Ok, someone brought up `BarChart` and `ScalingFunctions`, so here we go....

```
BarChart[Ordering /@ data, ChartLayout -> "Overlapped", 
 Joined -> Automatic, BarSpacing -> 0, ChartElementFunction -> ({} &),
  ChartStyle -> 1, ScalingFunctions -> "Reverse", Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, False}}, PlotRange -> {All, All}, 
 BaseStyle -> Thickness[0.01]]
```

[image: BarChart-based solution]

(but the `ListPlot` solution is probably easier.  Too bad it doesn't support `ScalingFunctions` yet.)

Comment: Actually, this one's great because it can handle the case where cars don't finish.  It worked right out of the box for me, thanks!

Comment: @BrettChampion, `ScalingFunctions -> "Reverse"` is supported by both `Plot` and `ListLinePlot` already.

Answer (score 3):

How about now showing the y-axes at all:

```
data = {{1, 3, 2, 4},
   {1, 3, 2, 4},
   {1, 3, 4, 2},
   {3, 1, 4, 2},
   {3, 1, 4, 2},
   {3, 4, 1, 2}};

ListLinePlot[Table[Position[5 - data, x], {x, 4}], 
 Axes -> {True, False}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

I am going to leave up this "clever" implementation because I like it, but David's answer is far more robust.

```
laps = 
  {{1, 3, 2, 4},
   {1, 3, 2, 4},
   {1, 3, 4, 2},
   {3, 1, 4, 2},
   {3, 1, 4, 2},
   {3, 4, 1, 2}};

ListLinePlot[
  -Thread[Ordering /@ laps],
  AxesOrigin -> {1, 0}, PlotStyle -> Thick,
  Ticks -> {All, Array[{-#, #} &, 4]}
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

`ScalingFunctions` now appears to work with `ListLinePlot`

```
data = {{1, 3, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 2, 4}, {1, 3, 4, 2}, {3, 1, 4, 2}, {3, 1,
     4, 2}, {3, 4, 1, 2}};
ListLinePlot[Table[Position[data, x], {x, 4}], 
 ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}, AxesOrigin -> {1, -5}]
```

I have no idea why the `AxesOrigin` y-coordinate needs to be negative.

[image: Mathematica graphics]