# Motorsport Lap Chart Revisited

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, plot

This is my first time posting so I apologize if asking a new question based on a pre-exisitng one is bad form.

I am trying to create a "lap chart" similar to the one presented here:

[Motorsport Lap Chart using ListLinePlot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5655224/motorsport-lap-chart-using-listlineplot)

My need has a bit of a twist. I am charting the lap positions for a different sport and my data is structured differently. The data is listed by team and the position the team was in at the completion of each lap. For example, here is a sample of the data:

```
BRA = {03, 01, 01, 01};
CAN = {14, 14, 06, 10};
CRO = {10, 08, 11, 12};
DEN = {05, 05, 04, 11};
FRA = {13, 11, 14, 13};
GBR = {04, 02, 02, 02};
GER = {15, 15, 12, 09};
GRE = {16, 16, 16, 16};
IRL = {01, 03, 08, 06};
NOR = {02, 04, 09, 05};
NZL = {06, 06, 05, 08};
POL = {08, 07, 03, 03};
POR = {11, 13, 15, 15};
SUI = {07, 09, 10, 07};
SWE = {09, 10, 07, 04};
USA = {12, 12, 13, 14};
```

In this example Brazil was in third place at the end of the first lap and then moved into first by the end of the second, holding the place for the third lap and then to the finish.

I have created the chart I need by manually retyping the data in a format to fit the code posted in the earlier example, but there has to be a more efficient way. Any suggestions are appreciated.

One other question... currently the positions at the end of a given lap are spaced evenly apart, however in the real race first place was 20 seconds ahead of second who was perhaps 10 seconds ahead of third. Is there a way to plot each position to reflect the relative time ahead of the next competitor?

Here is my current working code:

```
data = {{09, 10, 01, 06, 04, 11, 14, 12, 15, 03, 13, 16, 05, 02, 07, 08}, 
{01, 06, 09, 10, 04, 11, 12, 03, 14, 15, 05, 16, 13, 02, 07, 08}, 
{01, 06, 12, 04, 11, 02, 15, 09, 10, 14, 03, 07, 16, 05, 13, 08}, 
{01, 06, 12, 15, 10, 09, 14, 11, 07, 02, 04, 03, 05, 16, 13, 08}};

{p, n} = {Max@data, Length@data};

ListLinePlot[
 Replace[Array[data~Position~# &, 
   p], {lap_, y_} :> {lap - 1, -y}, {2}], 

Frame -> True,

FrameLabel -> {"Rounding", "Position", "Rounding", 
   "Final Positions"}, GridLines -> {Range[0, n + 1], None},

FrameTicks -> {
{{{-1, "IRL"}, {-2, "NOR"}, {-3, "BRA"}, {-4, "GBR"}, {-5, 
  "DEN"}, {-6, "NZL"}, {-7, "SUI"}, {-8, "POL"}, {-9, 
  "SWE"}, {-10, "CRO"}, {-11, "POR"}, {-12, "USA"}, {-13, 
  "FRA"}, {-14, "CAN"}, {-15, "GER"}, {-16, "GRE"}},

 {{-1, "1 BRA"}, {-2, "2 GBR"}, {-3, "3 POL"}, {-4, "4 SWE"}, {-5, 
  "5 NOR"}, {-6, "6 IRL"}, {-7, "7 SUI"}, {-8, "8 NZL"}, {-9, 
  "9 GER"}, {-10, "10 CAN"}, {-11, "11 DEN"}, {-12, 
  "12 CRO"}, {-13, "13 FRA"}, {-14, "14 USA"}, {-15, 
  "15 POR"}, {-16, "16 GRE"}}},

{{{0, "W1"}, {1, "L1"}, {2, "W2"}, {3, "F"}},
{{0, "W1"}, {1, "L1"}, {2, "W2"}, {3, "F"}}}},

PlotRange -> {Automatic, {-.7, -.3 - p}},

PlotStyle -> Thickness[.003]]
```

Comment: Related http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/66581

Answer (score 5):

Here you have how to reformat your data with minimal manual effort.

```
tot = {
  BRA = {03, 01, 01, 01},  CAN = {14, 14, 06, 10},  CRO = {10, 08, 11, 12},  
  DEN = {05, 05, 04, 11},  FRA = {13, 11, 14, 13},  GBR = {04, 02, 02, 02},
  GER = {15, 15, 12, 09},  GRE = {16, 16, 16, 16},  IRL = {01, 03, 08, 06},
  NOR = {02, 04, 09, 05},  NZL = {06, 06, 05, 08},  POL = {08, 07, 03, 03},
  POR = {11, 13, 15, 15},  SUI = {07, 09, 10, 07},  SWE = {09, 10, 07, 04},
  USA = {12, 12, 13, 14}}
```

then do

```
data = Ordering /@ Transpose@tot
```

and using @DavidCarraher's answer in the question you mentioned.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

If you have the timings for each team (for each lap), here is a skeleton for plotting a time scaled plot:

```
lapTimes   = RandomReal[{0, 1}, {10, 5}];(*ten teams,five laps*)
ListLinePlot[Accumulate /@ lapTimes, PlotRange -> {{1, 5}, All}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The lower line at the end is the winner (*less time consumed*)